# Laravel 4 - Container class: share function & closure logic

Tags: php, callback, closures, laravel-4, anonymous-function

I have a follow-up question to the one discussed here:
[Laravel core method confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758936/laravel-core-method-confusion/17295616#17295616)

I am in the same situation as driechel (author of question above) has been before, currently getting used to Laravel 4 FW and examining the core. Although a precise answer has been given I still don't understand the logic and what is happening under the hood. So I would very much appreciate a further explanation.
I know this might be a duplicate but since I cannot post comments yet I'll give it a shot with a new question. Hope it' ok this way.

I have been looking at this from another angle starting at this article:
http://blog.joynag.net/2013/05/facades-in-laravel-4-and-static-methods-resolution/

When examining the call `File:get()` I finally end up at the ***Container class' share function*** which is called with this actual parameter `share(function() { return new Filesystem; }`.

What I just can't figure out is the use of `$container`. Especially at the second occurence within the closure:

`$object = $closure($container);`

Could you please clarify this again? Why is `$container` passed as a parameter here and what is actually contained in it? As far as I understand `$closure` at that point holds and executes `function() { return new Filesystem; }` which has no input parameter.

I am lost. Studied this and the PHP anonymous functions/closures now for two days straight and still can't figure it out. I neither understand the syntax of `$closure($container)` here nor the logic.

Answer (score 11):

For reference, this is the [`share` method @ v4.0.5](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v4.0.5/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php#L126).

So, what's happening here. I'll explain it in a couple of steps.

#### Calling The Share Method

As you pointed out this method is called from service providers. So, the `FilesystemServiceProvider` calls this method which looks something like this:

```php
$this->app['files'] = $this->app->share(function() { return new Filesystem; });
```

It's assigning the *return* value of this `share` method to a binding in the container. In a nutshell, that return value will be the new `Filesystem` instance that is returned in the closure.

#### So What Does Share Do?

The `share` method is just another way of defining a singleton in IoC container. All this can be a bit intimidating at first. Basically, Laravel itself is an IoC container. All the classes are bound as instances on the container. Sometimes these instances should be the *same* instance on every call.

If you take a look at the referencing method above on GitHub, you'll notice that inside the closure a static variable is defined. It then checks if that variable is null, and if it is it resolves the closure (this is the closure that returns our new `Filesystem` instance). Then it simply returns the variable.

Now, the next time you use `File::get()` it doesn't need to instantiate the `Filesystem` class again, because it's already been instantiated and stored in the static `$object` variable. So it simply returns the same object to you.

**So!** Really, you could replace the `$this->app['files']` line with this, and it would still work.

```
$this->app->instance('files', new Filesystem);
```

99% of services actually use the `share` method though because working inside a closure allows objects to be instantiated with more complex dependencies.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for this great answer, I wonder why it is not accepted ?
Anyway, Laravel made me finally grasp PHP (I am a long time JS developer) which wasn‘t a case with any other framework.