# Laravel 4 Container Internal Workings

Tags: laravel, closures, inversion-of-control, containers

I've been studying the laravel 4 container to get more knowledge of the internals of laravel and to upgrade my own skills in writing better code.

However i'm failing to understand 3 similar pieces of code.
I'll use the smallest snippet to keep this question clean.

Similar questions can be found in links below. Although people have replied with correct answers, I'm not satisfied with simply 'Knowing how to use it, but not knowing how it all works inside'. So i really hope someone can give an explanation to all this.

[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17296224/laravel-4-container-class-share-function-closure-logic)
[Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758936/laravel-core-method-confusion/17295616#17295616)

```
<?php namespace Illuminate\Container; use Closure, ArrayAccess, ReflectionParameter;

class BindingResolutionException extends \Exception {}

class Container implements ArrayAccess {

    /**
     * Wrap a Closure such that it is shared.
     *
     * @param  Closure  $closure
     * @return Closure
     */
    public function share(Closure $closure)
    {
        return function($container) use ($closure)
        {
            // We'll simply declare a static variable within the Closures and if
            // it has not been set we'll execute the given Closure to resolve
            // the value and return it back to the consumers of the method.
            static $object;

            if (is_null($object))
            {
                $object = $closure($container);
            }

            return $object;
        };
    } 

}
```

How does the share method know that the $container variable in that function is in fact an instance of Illuminate\Container? It isn't defined within the scope of that function.
Neither is it defined in the following example usecase (which wouldn't help anyway)

```
class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider{

    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app['auth'] = $this->app->share(function($app)
        {
            // Once the authentication service has actually been requested by the developer
            // we will set a variable in the application indicating such. This helps us
            // know that we need to set any queued cookies in the after event later.
            $app['auth.loaded'] = true;

            return new AuthManager($app);
        });
    }

}
```

I'd expect a different implementation, so here comes

```
class MyContainer{

    public function share(Closure $closure)
    {
        $container = $this;

        return function() use ($closure, $container)
        {
            static $object;

            if(is_null($object))
            {
                $object = $closure($container);
            }

            return $object;
        };
    }

}

$closure = function($container)
{
    var_dump($container);
};

$container = new MyContainer();
call_user_func($container->share($closure));
//dumps an instance of MyContainer -> which is the wanted behaviour

$container = new Illuminate\Container\Container();
call_user_func($container->share($closure));
//Throws a warning AND a notice
//Warning: Missing argument 1 for Illuminate\Container\Container::Illuminate\Container\{closure}() in /Users/thomas/Sites/Troll/vendor/illuminate/container/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 128
//NOTICE: Notice: Undefined variable: container in /Users/thomas/Sites/Troll/vendor/illuminate/container/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 137
//and even worse the output of the var_dump is NULL
```

I have the same problem in understanding the extend and the bind method, which both have the same implementation of passing a none-existing parameter as a closure argument, but i cannot grasp how it is resolved to the container instance itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of `Container::share()` is a function that takes one argument: the container itself. In order to call it externally, you'd have to do this:

```
$closure = function ($container) {
    var_dump($container);
};

$container = new Illuminate\Container\Container();
call_user_func($container->share($closure), $container);
```

The reason for this is due to how service definitions work. The intended use of `share` is to wrap around a service definition.

Like this:

```
$container = new Illuminate\Container\Container();
$container['foo'] = $container->share(function ($container) { return new Foo(); });
```

When you access a service, like this:

```
var_dump($container['foo']);
```

It checks if the value is callable, and if it is, it will try to call it as a function. If you leave off the `share`, you will get a new `Foo` instance every time. The `share` memoizes the instance and returns the same one every time.

To re-iterate, the `$container` argument in the function returned from `share` is there because that's how service creation works. The service definition ("factory" function that you "set" on the container) is just a function that takes a container and returns the instance of the service it is creating.

Since `offsetGet()` it is expecting the definition to take a `$container` argument, that's what `share` returns.

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood the question, i know why and how to use it. My question is, how does the container know how to resolve the $container argument in your closure example, as it is never defined (at least not to my knowledge), except in the case where you use the call_user_func($container->share($closure), $container), but i don't see that anywhere in the container itself? Or perhaps i'm missing something really important here?

Comment: Read the last sentence from my answer. `offsetGet` always calls the closure passing it the `$container`.

Comment: I knew that, it just calls make function, but now apparently i missed a really important part in the build method (coming from the make method). I skipped those first few lines all the time, especially `return $concrete($this, $parameters);` You helped me in finding that important part i missed, therefor i'll accept your answer :-) I might have been trying to long, should've just taken a break.I hate this 'O my, how can i be so stupid' feeling :P. thx a BUNCH. btw, it's not the offsetGet that takes a $container argument, that just takes a key to your binding to tell it what binding to resolve

Comment: @Bodybag "therefor i'll accept your answer" as if you have many other answers to choose from!